# How to transpose data frame by a column and also group by each column value in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset like that:

RULE     |   GENERATION
A       |       1
B       |    1
C       |    1
D       |    2

I would like this output:

1           |             2
A           |          D
B           |
C            |

At this time i tried spread, aggregate and also a lot of functions, but still no have the desire result. I want to group by "GENERATION" and make its categories the column name of the new dataset where each column have the values with same order of the first dataset.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but can you provide reproducible example and be more clear with your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
 df<-data.frame(x=c(letters[1:4]),y=c(1,1,1,2))

 df%>%
   group_by(y)%>%
   mutate(num=row_number())%>%
   spread(y,x)%>%
   select(-num)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  `1`   `2`  
  <fct> <fct>
1 a     d    
2 b     NA   
3 c     NA
```

Comment: Thanks jyked, that's exactly i tried to do.Try many other post solutions, but none came close to what I wanted to do. Best Regards.

Comment: @RevanKnight can u pls mark my answer as the right one?